# How to bind a ServerSocket to an InetAddress?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

The usual java way is:

```
new ServerSocket(8765,0,"192.168.178.100");
```

I'm using the `spring` `TcpNioServerConnectionFactory` to create the socket. How can I set the desired `InetAddress` there?

Comment: By setting the `localAddress` property on it?

Comment: Indeed, great! Would you mind adding this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`TcpNioServerConnectionFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/api/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/TcpNioServerConnectionFactory.html) exposes a [`localAddress`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/api/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/AbstractServerConnectionFactory.html#setLocalAddress-java.lang.String-) propery which you can set.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioServerConnectionFactory">
    <property name="localAddress" value="192.168.178.100" />
</bean>
```